# How do behave the AP during monitoring mode?

Tags: wireless, monitoring, access-point

I want to know how to solve the communication with associated wifi devices when AP switch to monitoring mode.
Because I want to use the monitoring mode without effects the mobile that was associated in that time.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information to help you. Give us more information on the hardware you are using and what setup. Different vendors could define monitoring mode in different ways so it's important to know what vendor/hardware you are using before anyone can help you.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I am using LinksysWRT54GL and runinng OpentWRT.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Monitor Mode provides constant channel scanning with attack detection and forensics (packet capture) capabilities. Capture packets regardless of connected network. No association to AP needed (and no authentication). Because it is not connected to a network, you can't process the Wi-Fi frames. If you switch your AP into monitor mode all clients will be dissociated from this AP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful reply. I am just want to know also if it possible to create two interfaces in which one can be  use for monitoring mode and other use as AP mode. Because I am new and I dont have knowledge about that

Comment: The interface that would be used for monitoring would be the actual radio itself. Looking at the specs of the router, it appears it only has 1 x 2.4Ghz radio? You must use that to do the monitoring and it's the only wireless interface I believe.